# How to adapt xml bean into spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I have an interceptor written in XML:

```
<bean class ="com.packt.webstore.interceptor.AuditingInterceptor"/> 
<bean class ="com.packt.webstore.interceptor.PromoCodeInterceptor" > 
    <property name="promoCode" value ="OF3RTA"/> 
    <property name="errorRedirect" value="invalidPromoCode"/> 
    <property name ="offerRedirect" value ="products"/> 
</bean >
```

How do I write the same thing in Spring Boot? I tried this:

```
@Bean
PromoCodeInterceptor promoCodeInterceptor() {
    PromoCodeInterceptor promoCodeInterceptor = new PromoCodeInterceptor();
    promoCodeInterceptor.setPromoCode("OF3RTA");
    promoCodeInterceptor.setErrorReidect("invalidPromoCode");
    promoCodeInterceptor.setOfferRedirect("products");
    return promoCodeInterceptor;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

///edit

And what about this one?

```
<bean id="productValidator" 
class="com.packt.webstore.validator.ProductValidator">
  <property name="springValidators"> 
    <set> 
       <ref bean = "unitsInStockValidator"/> 
    </set > 
  </property> 
 </bean >

<bean id ="unitsInStockValidator" class 
="com.packt.webstore.validator.UnitsInStockValidator"/>
```

This code is ok?

```
@Bean
public ProductValidator productValidator() {
ProductValidator productValidator = new ProductValidator();
productValidator.setSpringValidators(unitsInStockValidator());
return productValidator;
}

@Bean
public UnitsInStockValidator unitsInStockValidator() {
  UnitsInStockValidator unitsInStockValidator = new UnitsInStockValidator();
  return unitsInStockValidator;
}
```

Comment: It should work. Do you have `@Configuration` annotation on your class?

Comment: No, i have @Component. Should i change it? Should i use InterceptorRegistry to registry this interceptor?

Comment: Only registering an interceptor isn't enough, you will also have to add it to the `interceptorRegistry` much in the same way you use (probably)  `<mvc:interceptors>` in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Bean` annotations working only in classes marked with `@Configuration`. 
Create new class and put your bean definition in it

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public PromoCodeInterceptor promoCodeInterceptor() {
        PromoCodeInterceptor promoCodeInterceptor = new PromoCodeInterceptor();
        promoCodeInterceptor.setPromoCode("OF3RTA");
        promoCodeInterceptor.setErrorReidect("invalidPromoCode");
        promoCodeInterceptor.setOfferRedirect("products");
        return promoCodeInterceptor;
    }
}
```

Comment: They also work in `@Component`, this is the so called lite-mode.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you take a look and asnwer, please?